# Crawl webpage which are rendered via JavaScript. PhtantomJs or any other tool?

Tags: javascript, html, web-crawler, phantomjs

I'm building a tool to crawl a page and store its html locally.

Also load that HTML on a webpage using iframe. So I have unbind and bind events on the crawled page.

I'm using PhantomJS to get the webpage data.

Web pages that render data via JavaScript are not feasible to crawl. Is there any way in PhantomJs to do so ?

Code to get web page data after page has loaded using PhantomJs is :

PHP code to shell execute phantomJs command

```
$shelldata = exec(PHATOM_JS_PATH."bin/phantomjs ".PHATOM_JS_PATH."/phantomcode.js $WEB_URL > webpage.html 2>&1");
```

Sample 1

```
var system = require('system');
var page = require('webpage').create();
var args = system.args;

page.onLoadFinished = function(status) {
//  console.log('Status: ' + status);
    console.log(page.content);
    phantom.exit();
};

if(args.length > 1){
    page.open(args[1], function(status) {
        if(status == "success"){
        }else{
            console.log("Invalid");
            phantom.exit();
        }
    });

}else{
    console.log("Invalid");
    phantom.exit();
}
```

Sample 2

```
var system = require('system');
var page = require('webpage').create();
var args = system.args;

if(args.length > 1){
    page.open(args[1], function(status) {
        if(status == "success"){
            setTimeout(function() {
                console.log(page.content);
                phantom.exit();
            }, 200);
        }else{
            console.log("Invalid");
            phantom.exit();
        }
    });
}else{
    console.log("Invalid");
    phantom.exit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of using SetTimeout with 200ms I think it will be better to inject scrolling down a script to the website  you want to download, that's how you avoid cases of sites using **windowing**

here is an exmaple made with [puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer)  written in node

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");
const fs = require("fs");

const injectionPath = "scrollInjection.js";

const writeContent = (content)=>{
  fs.writeFile("./test/pageoutput", content, function(err) {
    if(err) {
        return console.log(err);
    }
    console.log("The file was saved!");
}); 
}


const delay = time => {
  return new Promise(function(resolve) {
    setTimeout(resolve, time);
  });
};

let run = async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  //wait for page to fully loaded
  await page.goto(
    "URL TO GO TO"
  );

  //inject scrolling down script
  await page
    .evaluate(fs.readFileSync(injectionPath, "utf8"))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));

  //scroll down for x sec
  await delay("HOW MUCH TIME TO SCROLL DOWN THE PAGE ");

  // get page content
  const html = await page.content();
  writeContent(html)
  await browser.close();
};
run();
```

injectionFile.js

```
function myTimer() {
  window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
}
var scroller = setInterval(function() {
    myTimer();
  }, 1000);
```